# Swift Binary Operator "<"

Tags: swift, operators, comparable

```
func min(_ numbers:Double...)->Double{

        var result:Double = 0.0
        for num in numbers{

            if num < numbers {

                result = num
            }
        }

    return result
}
```

Here in `if num < numbers` showing me error:

> Binary Operator "<" can not applied to operand of double and Double

Comment: You probably meant `if num < result {`, although that will give you an incorrect results if all of you values are positive.

Comment: ohhh yes thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the error that you are mentioning is quite *wrong*, it should be:

> Binary Operator "<" can not applied to operand of Double and [Double]

means that you are trying to compare between a double and an array of doubles (`numbers`).

What are you trying to implement should be:

```
func min(_ numbers: Double...) -> Double? {
    guard var result = numbers.first else {
        return nil
    }

    for num in numbers {
        if result > num {
            result = num
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Usage:

```
if let minResult = min(2.1, 61.2, 33.6, 9.3, 4.2, 6.1, 6.1, 6.1, 3.4) {
    print(minResult) // 2.1
}

let nilResult = min() // nil
```

Note that `min` should returns an *optional* value, because -as mentioned in the code snippet- a function with variadic parameter is able to take 0 parameters without using the label.

**Also:**

I would recommend to use [min()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687893-min) array method, as follows:

```
func min(_ numbers: Double...) -> Double? {
    return numbers.min()
}
```

The output should be the same...

Comment: 'numbers.first` will always have a value, so you can just force unwrap it and lose the optional return.

Comment: @vacawama Edited, please advice :)

Comment: Oops, I lied.  You can call a variadic parameter with `0` arguments if you don't use the `label`.  What an annoying feature.  So you have the choice of forcing the caller to use the label or to return an optional like you were doing before.

Comment: @vacawama that's right, implementing `let test = min()` is legal (but not logical), I'll return it as an optional.

Comment: Define min like this: `func min(_ first: Double, _ numbers: Double...) -> Double {`.  Then you'll have a first.

Comment: Swift already defines a top level min function, so there is no reason for the OP to write this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
let numbers = [1.1, 6.2, 3.1, 9.3, 4.2, 6.1]
```

Swift 3:

```
numbers.min()
numbers.max()
```

Swift 2:

```
numbers.minElement()
numbers.maxElement()
```

Comment: yes i can use this but i want to know how can compare with a array Element ?

Comment: @EkramulHoque you want check Double with [Double] and this operation is wrong and you get this compile error:
Binary Operator "<" can not applied to operand of Double and [Double]